# JSON path results name doesn't match. How to fix this?

Tags: api, rest

Let me know where i am wrong. Unable to debug. Expected: Yauatcha Kolkata, But i am getting Null

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;

    public class basics {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            RestAssured.baseURI="https://maps.googleapis.com";
            
            given().
            param("loacation","22.5342,88.3723").
            param("radius","1500").
            param("key","APIKEY").
            when().
            get("/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json").
            then().assertThat().statusCode(200).and().contentType(ContentType.JSON).and().
            body("results[0].name",equalTo("Yauatcha Kolkata"));
            
            
        }
    
    }
```

RESPONSE:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path results[0].name doesn't match.
Expected: Yauatcha Kolkata
Actual: null

JSON:

{
"html_attributions": [],
"next_page_token": "CpQEDgIAAHOfRqrJgPLEqKIoYdUYaTCYblDDFTL22srIUsWknKVbSkKDBO9QzlgNxl-LyHqy74daFnAhMIYfebNV3y03almGx85Zvfhye6yTroZqA9qyT_3E1LfO4czm14fpjfguZut1yfne4XEVl5lP2TJ2WbA0BXRdAZA55_RfxLED_kQkRdM7vX7WolTAYEB14VdKCcRqu7LZwCEV4QHyzN4Gg9EFkBzWCtVlJiITNOFIkZR-PR8hRBGB3HxFawbrIHLVfzIYq-XgoMX7imkPYFKQt2CLkfalJEmyFVbeO5Pr2-CnH99tbvlrWi7TnbUkFtU768UHSRrnMyKpKqukIi5b1_0Tv2_1hK19SCF6pOAZA1Zf7Mc2KQDvAUUUpDk7D2TouhW9yG88g1CVgajGO0cPHNfeE-Sw5X_bu4GoLw1AWh0T4RVmg8VXpgJK9O2pJBwBcw-q4GoCZ0rcs0xsDYOuAmCEhIAVoe2D9tvw9sKCxg5e4dGp0WKWoIfDeN3rCEYPLW-zo-Md1XhEDkjLNKVX3uVd6hf8m4k5yLb00QXAcR8gKS5Xws7nBf1KKtLdLOP9YdUmDZ_xyUfnHxla-yPo2Bo0YXu91aM0FpMXrbUKxKjc8HOPYSqymHQrpU2BhRYNqIEbIogEkLUzM9jOKljtojF9MYuj-k_ZtlBDeHhl2TkaF8fQVgRhzEDD1xT6CIk1FxIQ4fViZqMN2fjImVqbMCYqQhoUkf4mRLHoPr8YSowaSB6Kbxd8Pec",
"results": [
{
"business_status": "OPERATIONAL",
"geometry": {
"location": {
"lat": 22.539053,
"lng": 88.3656771
},
"viewport": {
"northeast": {
"lat": 22.54042742989272,
"lng": 88.36691247989273
},
"southwest": {
"lat": 22.53772777010728,
"lng": 88.36421282010728
}
}
},
"icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
"id": "517dd99ba04947a72fad1a8e1a3ff6affbd0e8b7",
"name": "Yauatcha Kolkata",
"opening_hours": {
"open_now": false
},
"photos": [
{
"height": 3096,
"html_attributions": [
"<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/116458134057536437944">Soumita Biswas"
],
"photo_reference": "CmRaAAAAm4Sw_wT4AE9egVsywWd7dHQZwRIrvG_lWhhLfODJYR43oZewf7ywmiAp6esseQwhWZec5a-V8PzsfUuwDZ4VvjEBMEPbAHAFaLyf7z-wMtPKvaovM9y_9UgUX_eAs2-QEhBGbJlAHw0D9yZqvjHNMkusGhQhOy43KDGmuJgnAyHjRwUFEaHc8w",
"width": 4128
}
],
"place_id": "ChIJyUdILt52AjoRGyAmYKqbOdE",
"plus_code": {
"compound_code": "G9Q8+J7 Ballygunge, Kolkata, West Bengal",
"global_code": "7MJCG9Q8+J7"
},
"price_level": 3,
"rating": 4.4,
"reference": "ChIJyUdILt52AjoRGyAmYKqbOdE",
"scope": "GOOGLE",
"types": [
"bakery",
"cafe",
"bar",
"restaurant",
"food",
"point_of_interest",
"store",
"establishment"
],
"user_ratings_total": 866,
"vicinity": "Park Circus, 5th Floor, Quest Mall, Syed Amir Ali Ave, Beck Bagan, Ballygunge, Kolkata"
},

Comment: It's hard to say why a test doesn't pass if we can't see the data it's testing. Please share the JSON output

Comment: Shared, let me know if that works

Comment: Try using the formatting feature so it's readable!